# Controlling Windows Update frequency?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Is it possible to control how often Windows Update checks for available updates?  I would imagine a registry hack is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 7, you can use Local Group Policies to set Windows Update detection frequency.

Run this command:

```
gpedit.msc
```

And, on `Computer/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Update`,  set the option that says `Automatic Update detection frequency` to the desired frequency.

Note, nonetheless, that although detection can occur even hourly, installation will occur on a daily basis, minimum.

Indeed, you can set installations to be applied immediately, but this only happens to important updates that don't need a reboot (or to updates with a due date in the past, if you are using a WSUS server).

Answer (score 3):

You can read this Microsoft KB article here:  [KB 326693](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;326693), or simply run a task to do it whenever you want, with the command line option of:

`wuauclt /detectnow`.

Either way you do it, it is rather quick, easy and simple to setup.